# Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with networking homework assignment

Tags: java, exception, networking, heap-memory

I am currently writing a networking assignment for one of my college classes and I am running into a bit of a problem. This assignment consists of a setting up a set of nodes that communicate with each other over sockets using a predefined set of messages. These messages must be able to be constructed from byte data that is sent back and fourth of the sockets.

Here is an example of a method inside of one of the messages that processes data from a byte []:

```
    public void processData(byte [] data) throws IOException 
{
    DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
    //get the status code
    statusCode = (byte)stream.read();
    System.out.println("Status Code: "+statusCode);

    //get the additional info
    byte [] additionalInfoData = new byte[stream.readInt()];
    stream.read(additionalInfoData, 0, additionalInfoData.length);
    additionalInfo = new String(additionalInfoData);
    System.out.println("additionalInfo: "+statusCode);

    stream.close();

}
```

When I run the program, and it reaches this point (this is after the first message has been sent), it halts on

```
    byte [] additionalInfoData = new byte[stream.readInt()];
```

with this exception:

`Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at cdn.wireformats.RegisterResponse.processData(RegisterResponse.java:58)
    at cdn.wireformats.RegisterResponse.<init>(RegisterResponse.java:31)
    at cdn.wireformats.WireFormatFactory.getWireFormatMessage(WireFormatFactory.java:22)
    at cdn.communications.Link.readMessage(Link.java:62)
    at cdn.communications.Link.run(Link.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)`

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem? Am I reading data from the byte [] incorrectly?

Comment: How big is the stream, i.e. what does `stream.readInt()` return? How much memory do you give the JVM? Do you set the max memory at all or leave it the default? Which JVM - Hotspot, JRockit, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that the value you get from `stream.readInt()` isn't what you expect. I'd recommend printing it out and making sure it's correct.

There could be an [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue, or it could be that the receiving code isn't 100% in line with the sending code.

Comment: This was the ticket. I double checked the data being read and it turns out I was reading a different byte value that was gigantic and it couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write

```
byte [] additionalInfoData = new byte[stream.readByte()];
```

Some general consideration about memory management which could be useful: the default heap space size is 64 Mb. I8n order to extend it, you need to start your JVM with a Xmx parameter.

```
java -Xmx512M
```